# Navbar remain to the center with my own width in large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have one navbar in one website that im building which is full width in large screen.
I am trying to make it in my own width for large screens and im stuck.

i have the code here

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: #242424;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    
}

.navbar a {
    color: #cccccc !important;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: #646464 !important;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Nav</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>



                </button>


            </div>


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

Do you have any suggestion of how can i make it lets say 800px for wide screens
and when its loaded in tablet to be normal width of all the tablet/smartphone screen?

Comment: `max-width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: use property width for custom width along with display:inline-block

Comment: @Jay it leaves the "contact" on the same place as before but it makes the navbar correct. How can we make "contact" to follow up the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the simplest way to do this: you can limit the container size with a custom class at whatever media query you'd like the `navbar` with be 800px, then just adjust the custom `container` color to the `navbar` color and the `navbar` background color so it matches the body or use transparent.

See working example.

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #242424;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #646464;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container.container-nav {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #242424;
  }
  .container.container-content {
    width: 800px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container container-nav">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle Nav</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">News</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container container-content">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Hello</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!